# How to merge multiple (npm) package.json files into one with Gulp?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, package.json

Lets assume I have a mainFolder and 3 subfolders (subFolderA, subfolderB, subfolderC).

And these subfolders all contain a package.json with dependencies and devDependencies. (mainFolder/subFolderA/package.json)

I want to combine them into a single package.json in mainFolder (mainFolder/package.json)

Is there an existing gulp package (or any other solution outside Gulp) to combine and merge package.json dependencies and devDependencies?

(Let's assume there will be no version conflict. If there is a solution also covers that case, thats great!)

Can you post an example gulpfile.js or explain other ways/tools.

Thank you

Answer (score 20):

You can try [`package-json-merge`](https://github.com/eromano/package-json-merge) npm module. To install it, use this command -

`npm install -g package-json-merge`

Then simply use below command to combine multiple package.json into a single one -

`package-json-merge package1.json package2.json .... packageN.json > package.json`

Comment: i like this solution, i can run in bash script

Answer (score 10):

You could try using this node package to merge package.json files:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-merge

**Edit following comment by @dur**

*Example:*

```
var merge = require('package-merge')
var fs = require('fs');

var dst = fs.readFileSync('package.a.json');
var src = fs.readFileSync('package.b.json');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/package.merged.json", merge(dst,src));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options:

[json-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-merge)

`json-merge package.json --parse="dependencies" package2.json --parse="devDependencies"`

[npm-deps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-deps) scans subdirectories for nested package.json files, and merges all the dependencies together in a single package.json file that is outputted to stdout.

A base template passed through standard input is used to produce the root package.json file. This allows package.json to be ignored by version control systems, which conflict with auto-generated files. Base package attributes, like name and version, can be stored in a separate file such as package-base.json, and kept in version control.

`$ cd my_cool_project
$ npm-deps < package-base.json > package.json`